# How to add value and store in Shared preference in android

Tags: android

I have an app in which I send server request and in response server gives me some data, At this point I want to store in `SharedPreference`.

In next server request I again find the length of data coming in response from server, at this point of time I want this length to add with previous save value in preference and same process again and again.

**Code for finding server response length:**

```
JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("data");
int arrayCount = posts.length();
```

Comment: You should search on Google first... if you do not have time to search, you have not time to ask...

Comment: and you do not guide ...if you dont know

Comment: after googling I ask question here

Comment: Then... one of two things, or you haven't looked well, or doesn't exist... Your questions it's so simple... there are thousands of entries in google about `SharedPreferences` and how it's works

Answer (score 0):

```
// write
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("length", arrayCount);
editor.apply();

// read
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
int length = prefs.getInt("length", 0);
```

If you want to add length value to previous stored value incrementally, do something like this:

```
JSONArray posts = response.optJSONArray("data");
int arrayCount = posts.length();

// read stored value
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
int length = prefs.getInt("length", 0);

// save incremental length
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putInt("length", length + arrayCount);
editor.apply();
```